# How to encode a webscraped image link in UTF-8 to ASCII but still have a functional link?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, utf-8, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to webscrape a link to an image to use it in my Kivy app. The problem is that the image adress has Polish signs in it (ę, ł , ó, ą) and I get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 36-37: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Kivy\lib\site-packages\kivy\loader.py", line 342, in _load_urllib
    fd = opener.open(request)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1250, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1117, in putrequest
    self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0142' in position 36: ordinal not in range(128)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] exiting mainloop and closing.
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is an example where you can see what I mean. On picture loads normaly, without errors, the second one outputs the `UnicodeEncodeError` and displays a black color.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

build_structure = """
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        AsyncImage:
            # This doesnt load because it's in UTF-8 and outputs the error above 
            # but it doesn't break the app.

            source: app.link_to_image_bad
        AsyncImage:
            # This one does load
            source: app.link_to_image_good
"""


class ImageApp(App):
    # This link has Polish signs in it so it will give the UnicodeEncodeError
    link_to_image_bad = "https://nowa.1lo.gorzow.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Szkoła-do-hymnu.png"

    link_to_image_good = "https://nowa.1lo.gorzow.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Olimpiada-statystyczna.png"

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(build_structure)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ImageApp().run()
```

Output of the code above:

[image: Output of the code]

Is there a way to avoid this error and still have a functional link?

Comment: It's not clear which part of your code tries to re-encode this to ASCII, or why. Is there any reason to not simply keep it in Unicode? Perhaps adding the full traceback would be useful.

Comment: I the code above, no part tries to re-encode it to ASCII, because I don't know how to do it, that's why I'm asking this question. It cannot be kept in UTF-8 since it gives an error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 36-37: ordinal not in range(128)`.

Comment: You can URL-encode the links so they are pure ASCII but still get interpreted correctly by the server. You have to experiment a bit but probably assume they use UTF-8 as the URL encoding. `from urllib.parse import quote_plus; url = quote_plus(url)`

Comment: Sadly, I still get the same error when I try to use your method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL should already be ASCII compatible. The traffic on Internet (aka HTTP) works so: only ASCII URLS (with additional restrictions). Browsers now tend to unescape URL. [the `%20` and other `%xx` character we saw in part in URL]. Note: now we have UTF-8 encoding, and on top a URL escaping. So, you should remember that you have two layers to encoding.

You should escape URL, see [URL quoting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting). I would use `quote()` and `unquote()`. On comments, we saw a `quote_plus()`, but that change also the space, useful some time, but it will change the meaning of original data.

EDIT:

Ok, I problems. there seems to be something strange on how kivy handle the URLS. `quote()` is meant only for the path part, not for the first part of URL.

As an hack (it doesn't work if you have a specific port: it will quote the `:` in front of the port):

```
url = 'https://nowa.1lo.gorzow.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Szkoła-do-hymnu.png'
url_split = url.split('//')
'//'.join([url_split[0], urllib.parse.quote(url_split[1]))
```

So you get the wanted: `'https://nowa.1lo.gorzow.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Szko%C5%82a-do-hymnu.png'` as used by browsers.

You may want to include it into your own functions (and maybe check if there is a port number, to exclude it from quoting).

But wait, maybe someone has the true solution for Kivy. I never use full qualified path (so with protocol and domain), so for me basic `quote()` is enough.

Comment: I added a full traceback to the question, maybe this will help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but could you specify how woyld you use these mtehods according to my example code? I tired using `link_to_image_bad = quote(link_to_image_bad)` but I now it doesn't load the image at all, as if the link was dead.

Comment: I edited the answer, adding the code. I forgot that quote will quote also the `:` in `https://`. So now my answer is ugly.